# MariaDB: how to join to another table on JSON array's element's field and selecting a value from the other table for each array element

Tags: json, mariadb, mysql-json

I have two tables, for example's sake I simplified it:

`Table A`

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ { "b_id": 1 }, { "b_id": 2 } ] |
| 2 | [ { "b_id": 2 }, { "b_id": 3 } ] |
| 3 | NULL |

`Table B`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | random |
| 2 | foo |
| 3 | bar |

I would like to select the `data` column from `Table A` but with each json array element including the corresponding `name` from `Table B`, so the result would look something like this

```
SELECt ... FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON ...
```

| data |
| --- |
| [ { "b_id": 1, "b_name": "random" }, { "b_id": 2, "b_name": "foo" } ] |
| [ { "b_id": 2, "b_name": "foo" }, { "b_id": 3, "b_name": "bar" } ] |
| NULL |

Edit: MariaDB version: 11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2004-log

Comment: Are you using a version of MariaDB with `JSON_TABLE()`?

Comment: If not, I think you'll need to write a stored procedure that loops over the elements in `A.data`.

Comment: JSON in SQL is a real PITA to use. Is there any chance you can normalize your tables to get rid of the JSON array?

Comment: `.. ON JSON_OVERLAPS(TableA.data, CONCAT('[ { "b_id": ', TableB.id,' }]')) ..`

Comment: Please specify exactly what version you are using. MariaDB and MySQL are not the same product. In particular they have different implementations of JSON support, so an answer for one is not necessarily relevant to the other. Run this query: `SELECT VERSION();` and tell us exactly what it returns.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I can use `JSON_TABLE`.

Comment: @BillKarwin: added version to the post.

Comment: This sounds like a case where you should have the data in columns, not hidden in Json.  And, since arrays are involved, that may involve extra tables such as a table with key-value pairs.

Comment: If you can use JSON_TABLE, that's what you should do. Please try to write it yourself. If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it. Hint: Use `JSON_TABLE()` to split the array into rows, and `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to put the result back into an array.